# How to entierly change the color schema of kdevelop to dark one?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, color-theme

I am trying to set a color dark schema to my KDevelop, but I am managing to set it only to the editor part, and not to the whole interface.

What I am getting is this:

[image]

while I am wanting something like [this](https://www.kdevelop.org/sites/kdevelop.org/files/photos/kdevelop.png):

[image: dark KDevelop screenshot]

Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: For newer Ubuntu answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310788/kdevelop-color-themes-with-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention KDevelop I assume that you are on Kubuntu, or at least running KDE. If so, then you need to change the settings for:

- Application appearance
- Workspace appearance

To do that:

Kmenu -> System Settings -> Application Appearance -> Colors

Once there, in the Scheme tab you will be presented with some options of schemes to select. If you cannot find one that you like, click the "Get New Themes" button on the right and install one that you like (or that looks like the example you provided).

Then you may need to change the window decorations option to match your new color scheme.

From System Settings go to:

Workspace Appearance -> Window Decorations

and select the one you like or that looks good with your previous "Colors" settings. Again, you can get more by clicking in "Get New Decorations" button down to the right.

Comment: but: 1. I have no kmenu; 2. In my System Settings I have no Application Appearance (just Appearance in the Personal group); 3. In Colors I have just a profile that has nothing to do with the colors of the applications colors ... It is similar to [this one](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Ygmw7HeOfYw/TwfS6NXj1RI/AAAAAAAAB5s/DcbEle9v1fQ/s1600/System+Settings+in+Ubuntu+12.04.png). Some more help please :)

Comment: @sop Since I don't use Ubuntu, I can't really help you there. Sorry. To make my answer somewhat more "general": you are changing the parameters that KDevelop can handle, but the color of the rest of the application is handled by Ubuntu, so you have to modify those parameters from the Ubuntu settings, and not from within KDevelop. See if [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/172280/how-do-i-change-the-theme-and-window-border-color) helps and let me know to update the answer.

Comment: Ok, let's start step by step: how can I see if I have Kubuntu or not?

Comment: @sop From the link you provided on your first comment it looks like you are using Ubuntu and not Kubuntu. Here are a couple of links that might help you better understand what does it mean to have one (Ubuntu) or the other (Kubuntu) [link](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9369), and [link2](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-distributions-5/can-i-install-ubuntu-in-kubuntu-477953/) (this is very old but it should still work). I don't like to install KDE software (i.e. Kdevelop) in Ubuntu and _viceversa_ .

Comment: Oh, I have installed kubuntu and now it is working...Thanks

Comment: I have to say that is an unfortunate limitation in Kdevelop